# Advanced Custom field for each post in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am using Advanced Custom Fields in order to show different banner image for each language with qTranslate plugin.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="linea">
            <?php if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='en') {
 ?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('banner')?>">
<?php }
else if(qtrans_getLanguage()=='es') {?>
                <img src="<?php the_field('banner_image_es')?>">
<?php }?>
        </section>
<section id="categoria1">
            <div class="pagewidth clearfix">
                    <div class="breadcrumbs" xmlns:v="http://rdf.data-vocabulary.org/#">
                        <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
                        {
                            bcn_display();
                        }?>
                    </div>
                    <h1 class="categoria-title"><span class="left"></span><b><?php single_term_title(); ?></b><span class="right"></span></h1>
            </div>
        </section>

        <section id="categoria2">
            <div class="pagewidth clearfix">

                <ul class="product-list">
                    <?php $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'productos','taxonomy'=>'categoria','term'=>'conformink-cunero-luxy','paged' => get_query_var('paged'))); ?>

                    <?php while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();?> 

                        <li>
                            <h5><a style="color: #f79646;"  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>  
                            <a class="verdetalle" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if( qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'es' ){ ?>Ver detalle<?php }else { ?>See More<?php } ?></a>
                            <!-- <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,120); ?></p> -->
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>   
                        </li>

                    <?php
    endwhile;
    wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>   
</div>
        </section>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The problem is that it keep showing the image of only one post on all templates, although I have already assigned the different images to different categories.

Can anyone help?

Comment: The above piece of code should not be the problem. In your question you are mentioning categories. Your code has got nothing to do with categories.

Comment: I have different products of different categories,
And assign two custom fields for this post type,
how do i get the banner image on each page according to the category ?
for now it shows same image on all pages.

Comment: Your above code snippet does not have to do anything with categories. Where is this code? On your `index.php`, `single.php`, `category.php`, ...?

Comment: Thanks for your reply
My code is in this file " taxonomy-categoria-organica-bebe.php " and my category name is "organica-bebe."

Comment: Have you checked if this template is actually used? I think it should be `category-organica-bebe.php` (according to https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates). Are the different flags attached to the posts or the category? Is the above code inside a loop? You should add more code from the template to get an answer.

Comment: Yes this template is used and show all the product with this category here is the complete code from this page (i edit my code)

Comment: To which "entitiy" are `the_field('banner')` and `the_field('banner_image_es')` attached? The category? The post?

Comment: Here what i do.
Create Advance Custom Field which has relation to Custom Post Type.
In custom post type i have different categories.
When i add any product and assign the category "organica-bebe" in addition select the images for Advance Custom field.
BUT ON organica-bebe page the custom field data is not shwoing.

Comment: You want to show a field that is attached to post outside of a loop on an archive page. That won't ever work. Sorry. Why are you only showing the `banner_image` once although you attach it to every post?

Comment: Basically i have multilingual site http://babymink.com.mx/demo/en/categoria/cuna-bebe/
and want to show different banner with different language on each post.
is there any way to achieve this ?
You can check all post's under the menu name "Catalog"
But now it shows same banner on all posts for each language although i set different banner for each post for different language .

Comment: If you want to show the banner on every post, you'll have to move it to the loop. Otherwise it won't show.

Comment: What kind of loop can you show any sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the banner to show up on every post you'll have to move the section inside the loop:

```
<section id="categoria2">
    <div class="pagewidth clearfix">

        <ul class="product-list">
            <?php 
            $my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'productos','taxonomy'=>'categoria','term'=>'conformink-cunero-luxy','paged' => get_query_var('paged')));

            if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();?> 

            <li>
                <section id="linea">
                    <?php if ( qtrans_getLanguage() == 'en' ) : ?>
                        <img src="<?php the_field('banner'); ?>">
                    <?php elseif ( qtrans_getLanguage() == 'es' ) : ?>
                        <img src="<?php the_field('banner_image_es'); ?>">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </section>
                <h5><a style="color: #f79646;"  href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>  
                <a class="verdetalle" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php if( qtranxf_getLanguage() == 'es' ){ ?>Ver detalle<?php }else { ?>See More<?php } ?></a>
                <!-- <p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,120); ?></p> -->
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></a>   
            </li>
            <?php
            endwhile; endif;
            wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $my_query ) );
            wp_reset_query(); ?>
        </ul>   
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have update my answer. Remove the `category_<ID>` part. The post ID is passed as default to `get_field()`.

Comment: Much thanks for your help i think it is working let me check it.

Comment: I got it, it  shows banner from all those posts which have this category.
is there any way to restrict that?

Comment: Actually here is confusion i just want to show the banner of same category.
the issue is if this category have more then one post it means each post has 2 banners so loop shows all post's banner from current category.

Comment: But above you said that the banner is attached to the post and not the category... I think I don't understand what you are trying to achieve, sorry.

Comment: You are right it's confusion here.
but i really appriciate your help thanks. going to make it as a solution because it solve my problem